# Writing to the database every second

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write code which adds data to the firebase every second for 10 seconds. The problem with this code is that it is writing new data to the database instaneously and without termination. How can I fix setInterval so that it only writes code every second for 10 seconds?

```
exports.addWelcomeMessages = functions.firestore.document('messages/{messageId}').onCreate(
  async (snapshot) => {
    const text = snapshot.data().text;
    let timerId = setInterval(() =>
      admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({
        name: 'Firebase Bot',
        profilePicUrl: '/images/firebase-logo.png', // Firebase logo
        text:  text,
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); alert('stop'); }, 10000);
  console.log('Welcome message written to database.');
});
```

Comment: Create a timer, increase the value in the `setInterval` and check if its value is greater  than or equal to `x`

Comment: How do I create a timer? I'm sorry if thats a dumb question, I'm very new to node.js

Comment: Try this page: [Timers in Node.js and beyond](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/)